# Can not install Spotify on 15.10: libssl0.9.8 problem

Tags: 15.10, spotify

Finished the first three steps given [here](https://www.spotify.com/tr/download/linux/)

However after performing step 4 that is

```
~$ sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

I get the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spotify-client : Depends: libssl0.9.8 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libavcodec53 but it is not installable or
                              libavcodec52 but it is not installable or
                              libavcodec-extra-53 but it is not installable or
                              libavcodec-extra-52 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libavformat53 but it is not installable or
                              libavformat52 but it is not installable or
                              libavformat-extra-53 but it is not installable or
                              libavformat-extra-52 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

as well but no luck so far.

What should I do?

Comment: @chaskes yes I followed the instructions at the given link. I haven't installed the spotify though. The problem is that I can not install it already. And therefore I can't purge it.

Comment: @Flint I think that is that. I was using 64-bit on 14.04 and it was working perfectly. Any advises on how can I install libssl0.9.8 on 15.10? Is it possible?

Comment: @Flint Thanks! That's a good catch. You should make an answer.

Comment: @Flint I'll do that but still I don't use my computer for anything other than Skype and Spotify so it kinda lost haft of its use and I really don't want to go download x64 all over again and format reinstall the entire OS. I'd be really glad if you know a way of installing libssl0.9.8... Also, make sure to answer to the question so I can tick it. Thank you

Comment: @Flint well that is it. it is working perfectly. thank you flint. I seriously suggest you should post it as an answer since I believe it'll be pretty useful to others as well.

Comment: @SarpSTA: As you're a reputation 6 user: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby thanks, I'm new as a member but I know how to use stackexchange. still thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of posting this, the Packages index file in the official repo for both Spotify [32-bit](http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/non-free/binary-i386/Packages) and [64-bit](http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is somehow outdated (someone at Spotify needs to update these files) and contain information about previous spotify-client `.deb` release which still uses `libssl0.9.8`. But as `libssl0.9.8` is no longer available in the package repository of `Ubuntu 15.10` and onwards, that explains why apt barfed that dependency error when you tried to install from spotify official repo as outlined on its Linux download page

The latest 32-bit and also 64-bit `spotify-client` however do use `libssl1.00` now. As temporary solution for installing spotify until this repo issue is fixed, you'll have to download the deb binary manually. Go to this [link](http://repository.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/) on spotify repo. Then to install the downloaded deb, use `dpkg -i <debfile>`, followed by apt-get install -f to install need dependency if necessary

---

**Edit..**

It seems that Spotify repo has silently moved to `testing` channel for a while now and all the active developement on Linux build is first pushed into testing repo, according to some post on Spotify forum. I think you can say `stable` channel now is more or less abandoned which explains the whole issue with outdated Packages index files though the debs are not. So now instead of using stable channel as outlined in the Linux installation instruction on Spotify official site, you should be using `testing`. Change your Spotify repository from

`deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`

to

`deb http://repository.spotify.com testing non-free`

Comment: This is it guys.  `spotify-client` is the problem. For some reason, even though it is the actual official method of installing Spotify on Linux (since when you choose Install For Linux on the Spotify website it redirects you to [here](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/))both 32-bit and 64-bit versions are comparably outdated. Use the repository. Again, thanks for the help Flint.